# PHP AWS-SDK : multiple putObject using a role through MFA

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm tying to figure out why my second putObject fails and the first one not.

I have an IAM user only allowed to assume a role and this action is protected by an MFA.

Then I use the role to hit my S3 bucket.

I suspect that putObject call the STS API as many times as putObject is called.

Here is my script

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Noa
 * Date: 08/02/2018
 * Time: 18:14
 */

use Aws\Credentials\AssumeRoleCredentialProvider;
use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotEnv = new Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotEnv->load();

$token = readline("MFA:");

$stsClient = new StsClient([
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY"),
        'secret' => getenv("AWS_ACCESS_SECRET")
    ]
]);

$assumeRoleCredentials = new AssumeRoleCredentialProvider([
        'client' => $stsClient,
        'assume_role_params' => [
            'RoleArn' => getenv("AWS_ROLE"),
            'RoleSessionName' => 'test',
            'DurationSeconds' => 3600,
            'SerialNumber' => getenv("AWS_MFA_DEVICE"),
            'TokenCode' => $token
        ]
    ]
);

$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => $assumeRoleCredentials
]);


$client->putObject([
    'Body' => 'le test4',
    'Bucket' => getenv("AWS_BUCKET"),
    'Key' => 'test/test_'.uniqid().'.txt'
]);

$client->putObject([
    'Body' => 'le test4',
    'Bucket' => getenv("AWS_BUCKET"),
    'Key' => 'test/test_'.uniqid().'.txt'
]);
```

Raises this error, affect the 2nd putObject call:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://sts.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>AccessDeni (truncated...)
```

If someone has an idea, I'll be really grateful ^^

Answer (score 0):

found :D

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Noa
 * Date: 08/02/2018
 * Time: 18:14
 */


use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotEnv = new Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotEnv->load();

$token = readline("MFA:");


$stsClient = new StsClient([
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY"),
        'secret' => getenv("AWS_ACCESS_SECRET")
    ]
]);

$assumeRoleObject = $stsClient->assumeRole([
    'RoleArn' => getenv("AWS_ROLE"),
    'RoleSessionName' => 'test',
    'DurationSeconds' => 3600,
    'SerialNumber' => getenv("AWS_MFA_DEVICE"),
    'TokenCode' => $token
]);

$credentials = $assumeRoleObject['Credentials'];

$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        'secret' => $credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        'token' => $credentials['SessionToken']
    ]
]);


$client->putObject([
    'Body' => 'le test4',
    'Bucket' => getenv("AWS_BUCKET"),
    'Key' => 'test/test_'.uniqid().'.txt'
]);

$client->putObject([
    'Body' => 'le test4',
    'Bucket' => getenv("AWS_BUCKET"),
    'Key' => 'test/test_'.uniqid().'.txt'
]);
```

The problem was the AssumeRoleCredentialProvider middleware, I remove it and it's work :)